# Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool' parse.com push notification

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I'm Trying use push notification with swift&parse.com.And I'm taking this error.
How can I figure out this.

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.pushNotificationController = PushNotificationController()

    // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {

        let types:UIUserNotificationType = (.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
    }


 }//Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function expects a Boolean as return value.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
   // Your code.
   return true
}
```